# Positioning a block next to content

Tags: html, css

I'm going to display a `title` inside content of page. `title` is a php function `<?php the_title(); ?>` and content is another function `<?php the_content(); ?>`.

As you can see at image, here title is "The Best Widget ever in Android Mobile Phones" and content is what's next to it.

How can i positioning a `div` element like that to show `title`, between a area of content  ?

Img URL : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh5iC.jpg

Comment: Thats what float:left; was invented for. im sure there would be more to it than just that though

Comment: Please show your HTML output. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Chris Coyier has [something to tell you](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)!

Comment: @Diodeus that's not php, i talked about function to say that title is a dynamic value.

Comment: @Connor How about it's positioning between content ? what should be `display` property value ?

Comment: It's dynamic on the server, but all the browser sees is the HTML output, which is static. We're troubleshooting the HTML + CSS, not the PHP.

Comment: @Diodeus ok forget about php, clarify solution please

Comment: See the comment by jmeas. Important.

Comment: @Diodeus i saw that. but that doesn't fit my case! i really want a simple html+css example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what you are asking for is not so feasible, floats are calculated based on their order in the page, so there is no way to get a header *inside* a large chunk of text without actually placing the title *in between* paragraphs, which I know isn't possible in your case. But you cannot float an element higher or lower than where it actually is.

The closest solution here would be to float the header to the left with simple css, which would place the header at the top of the text, instead of the middle.

```
h1 {
float: left;
display: block;
width: 250px;
}
```

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aV8u/) with the outcome in both cases.

ps: and I know you said no PHP but if you really wanted what you were asking for, you can utilize the [excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) function (since I know you are using WP), and split the article between `excerpt()` and `content()` so you can place the title in between. Just a thought.

Comment: great! u understood what i wanted ;)